# Nutch fetched pages aren't being indexed into Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, nutch

Ok, so I'm trying to setup nutch to crawl a site and index the pages into solr. I'm currently using Nutch 1.9 with Solr 4.10.2 
I've followed these instructions: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search

The crawling appears to go just fine but when I check the collection on Solr (using the web ui) there are no documents indexed...any idea where I could check for problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem, I'll leave it as an answer in case anyone else has the same symptoms:

My problem was the proxy configuration. My linux box has the proxy configured to be applied system-wide, but I also had to configure Nutch to use the same proxy. Once I changed that, it started to work.

The configuration is under config/nutch-default.xml

**Edit with more info**

To be more specific, here is the Proxy configuration I had to change:

```
<property>
  <name>http.proxy.host</name>
  <value>xxx.xxx.xxx</value>
  <description>The proxy hostname.  If empty, no proxy is used.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific what option did you change and how?

Comment: @Mateva I added the example code, although if your nutch-default.xml file is the one that comes with the installation, then you need to only lookup the word "proxy" to find it.